# jQuery.ajax File Delete

Tags: php, jquery, file, delete-file

I have a jquery delete statement and it's only deleting the NEWEST upload on my files (using mysql) Say I had "file uploaded first", "file uploaded second", "file uploaded last(newest file)". If I click "file uploaded first or second", it deletes the newest (file uploaded third).

```
    $(document).on('click', '.del', function(){
    var sid = $(this).next('.hiddenVid').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: {id:sid}
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The thing is you only delete the same file right? What is `sid`? Does `alert(sid)` show the same thing?

Comment: How I have it layed out is like little buttons next to each. When I click the button on a certain row(for instance, the first file) I want it to delete THAT FILE, not the last one. sid is the vid just clearer incase I ever need to change something

Comment: `var sid = "$vid";`. You sure that `$vid` evaluates to a value in this statement? It's a PHP variable which you are trying to use in your jQuery??

Comment: The php variable reads just not as the right value? I guess you could say that.. Also, it's embedded in the PHP file.

Comment: perform delete in through post ajax and make sure server only entertain post requests only. delete through get is risky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is your error ->

```
var sid = "$vid";.
```

It will only produce the ID for the latest item that you put in.

Add an item to your echo statement so you can reference it later in the click function.

Add a reference to the vid in a hidden input.

**Change this**

```
$option = "<td><form method='POST'><button type='submit' name='del' class='del'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button></form></td>";
```

**To this**:

```
$option = "<td><form method='POST'><button type='submit' name='del' class='del'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button><input type='hidden' class='hiddenVid' value='".$vid."'/></td>";
```

Change your click function to reference the real sid now.

```
$(function(){
    $(".del").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parent();
        var sid = $(this).next('.hiddenVid').val();
        alert(sid);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: {id:sid}
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

If you want to return the rows after the update, you'll need to spit the data back to be printed, based on the above method you use to retrieve the rows and return them, you could reuse it.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']);
$DB->Query("DELETE FROM `files` WHERE `id`='$id'");

if(TRUE == (unlink("uploads/$id")):
    $DB->Query("SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `author`='$username'");
    $file = $DB->Get();
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($file as $key => $value){
        $n = $value['name'];
        $vid = $value['id'];
        $date = "<td>".$value['date']."</td>";
        $fname = "<td><a id='$vid' href='download.php?id=$vid'>$n</a></td>";
        $option = "<td><form method='POST'><button type='submit' name='del' class='del'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button></form></td>";
        $size = "<td>".filesize("uploads/".$vid."/".$value['name'])." bytes</td>";
        $obj->$i = $files = "<tr>".$fname.$size.$date.$option."</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($obj);
endif;
```

Now we need to change the click handler to expect a dataType and replace the existing data in the table.

```
$(function(){
    $(".del").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parent();
        var sid = $(this).next('.hiddenVid').val();
        alert(sid);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "delete.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id:sid},
            success: function(data){
              $('table').empty();
              $.each(data, function(i,obj){
                  $('table').append(obj);
              }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks. Can you post a little thing to make it refresh when it's done? The table row doesn't get removed until I refresh.

Comment: @user1678514 the `refresh` you're talking about is exactly what this method does. There isn't a "refresh" table method or something that you're looking for unless you've written the class for this. What the above does is to check if the unlink function actually works. it returns `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`. if it's true, then we create a new object, create an iterator, then run a `for loop`. In this loop, we then tell it to push the `$files string` into the `object $obj`. Then, we encode this object and send it back. The ajax functione xpects json, so it evaluates the response.

Comment: I just meant refresh the page, haha.

Comment: Oh god. I feel like an ass. `success: function(){ window.location.reload() }`

Comment: I've tried that... I think the return false is stopping that but when I remove "return false;", the whole thing breaks.

Comment: `$('.del').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();` change your cilck functions first line to that instead of return false. see if that works?

Comment: try `window.location.href = window.location.href`

Comment: can you `console.log('here')` within the `success:function(){}` of the `ajax call` and tell me if it runs?

Comment: success only runs if return false is there.

Comment: can you please add `error:function(){ console.log('error') }` to the ajax call to see if we have an error.

Comment: The reason success only returns under those conditions is because `.del` is a button that will submit the form. If you use return false, it stops the default form submission. otherwise, it will submit the form and reload the page. We're trying to avoid that. `e.preventDefault()` will do the same thing, without stopping Propagation.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to show the current click function that you're using in it's entirety? There's no reason that we shouldn't get a response back of some sort.

Comment: I don't know man, I'll be honest. I'm at a loss right here. We're sure the click event is firing all together, right? also `live` is deprecated, we choose to use `$(document).on('click', '.del', function(){`. where `$(document)` can be any static parent container.

Comment: Can we try and put a `console.log('here')` before the ajax response, in our click function, to ensure the event is indeed firing?

Comment: I edited the question. That's the code I currently have. Any ideas?

Comment: No. I'm all out of ideas as to why the ajax function returns nothing. What version of jQuery are you using?